# Relationship between fine Selmer groups and class groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory

Given an elliptic curve $E_{/\mathbb{Q}}$ and an odd prime number $p$, let $S$ be the set of primes consisting of $p$ and the primes at which $E$ has bad reduction. The fine Selmer group $R_{p^\infty}(E/\mathbb{Q}_{cyc})$ simply consists of all Galois cohomology classes in $H^1(\mathbb{Q}_S/\mathbb{Q}_{cyc}, E[p^\infty])$ that are trivial at primes in $S$. Its Pontryagin dual is cofinitely generated and cotorsion over the Iwasawa algebra, it's $\mu$-invariant is conjectured to be $0$ (even when the residual representation on $E[p]$ is reducible).

Let $F$ be the number field $\mathbb{Q}(E[p])$ cut out by the residual representation $\bar{\rho}:\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, i.e., the number field fixed by $ker \bar{\rho}$. It follows from Theorem 3.4 of "Fine Selmer groups of elliptic curves of p-adic Lie extensions" by Coates-Sujatha that $\mu=0$ for the fine Selmer group if and only if the classical $\mu=0$ conjecture holds for $F_{cyc}/F$. Thus, the $\mu=0$ conjecture for the fine Selmer group over $F_{cyc}$ is a special case of the classical $\mu=0$ conjecture for number fields studied by Iwasawa. In the special case when $E$ has Mordell-Weil rank $\leq 1$, it is possible for both $\mu$ and $\lambda$ to be $0$, i.e., for the fine Selmer group to have finite cardinality. In fact, this is expected for all but finitely many primes, according to a well-known conjecture of Wuthrich. In this special case, does one expect something similar for the Iwasawa $\lambda$-invariant of $F_{cyc}/F$? In particular if $\lambda=0$ for the fine Selmer over $F_{cyc}$ then, is $\lambda=0$ for the $p$-Hilbert class field extension of $F_{cyc}$?

Comment: Second question: Fixing $p$, it should be easy to find a curve $E$ with a trivial fine Selmer group. So if there were an implication to the classical $\lambda$-invariant, they all would have to be zero fro all $p$, which they are not.

Comment: @Wuthrich Here $F$ is the field cut out by $E[p]$, so it depends on both $E$ and $p$. Perhaps I have not understood your comment?

Comment: @Wuthrich It is indeed clear that at a prime $p$, there is an elliptic curve $E$ for which the fine Selmer is finite over $\mathbb{Q}_{cyc}$ (looking at elliptic curves such that $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is finite and non-zero). However, it is not so clear (to me) that there is one for which the fine Selmer over $F_{cyc}$ is finite, where $F=\mathbb{Q}(E[p])$. First of all one would need an elliptic curve for which the rank remains 0 or 1 in $F$.

Comment: You are right. I was considering the wrong $F$. Hmmmmm....